# Python - How to read this bin file?

Tags: python, numpy, bin

I have a .bin file saved using Matlab which consists of the following double values: `[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0]`

I wanna read this bin file and stores all the even values in a list and all odd values in another list. As an example, I would a result like this:

```
even_values = [2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0]
odd_values  = [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0]
```

I can read this entire bin file once. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
data = open('bin_file', 'rb')
all_values = np.fromfile(data,dtype=np.float32)
```

My question is:

Is there a way of read this bin file two times?

In the first time, I want to read only the even values and in the second time I wanna read the odd values. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just iterate over the `all_values` object twice?

Comment: Why not just load all the values once, and _then_ separate them?

Comment: also you are not using `with` to open the file, so don't forget to close it!

Comment: Yes. I can load it once but thought it might be a way to do this in just two calls from the read function.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Sembei Norimaki!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, should you be using `float` for comparing even and odd values? Anyway, just open the file and then create new numpy objects.

```
import numpy as np
with open('bin_file', 'rb') as data:
    all_values = np.fromfile(data, dtype=np.float32)
even_values = all_values[all_values % 2 == 0]
odd_values  = all_values[all_values % 2 == 1]
del all_values  # if you're really worried about memory
```